# Slick Carousel next and previous buttons showing above/below, rather than left/right

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using Slick Carousel [this](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and my "next" and "previous" arrows are appearing above and below my images, rather than on each side. I'm just looking for it to appear the way it does in the Slick docs.

The buttons aren't in the html, they're generated by the slick js.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="albumsCarousel">
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterQuit.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterVill.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/casio.jpg></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterWorried.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterFrost.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterWeird.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterOphelia.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterEnya.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterXiu.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterImpasse.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterV.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterThrone.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterSholi.png></div>
  <div><img class="slickImage" src=./images/betterPGirls2.png></div>
 </div>
```

here's the JS:
      $(document).ready(function(){

```
   $('.albumsCarousel').slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 3,
arrows: true,
cssEase: "ease",
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>',
prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>'
});
```

and here's the CSS (which I'm pretty sure isn't playing a role here):

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);/* fix for chrome not rendering */
   }
   .slick-dots {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please proivde a screenshot or a fiddle? It'd be much easier to get the scenario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem with slick; the navigations where above and under the image. but i solved it with this simple css.

```
.nextArrowBtn{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    color: #BFAFB2;
}
.prevArrowBtn{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    color: #BFAFB2;
}
```

Now in your slick configuration, add the classes above to the prevArrow and nextArrow attributes.

```
$("#slick-images").slick({
    nextArrow: '<i class="icon fa-arrow-right nextArrowBtn"></i>',
    prevArrow: '<i class="icon fa-arrow-left prevArrowBtn"></i>'
});
```

you can add other attributes as desired, optionally, you can also style the arrow to choice. but this little css positions the arrow right where you in the middle of the images. I hope this helps someone out there. Cheers!

Comment: After trying for half an hour you just saved my day. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

can you please remove next and previous arrow from option and try it. you can check here the working code also.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}
```

js

```
$(".single-item").slick({
    dots: true,
  infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 3,
cssEase: "ease",
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
});
```

Working code check here

https://jsfiddle.net/v8xbo5sz/

Try this if its work

```
$(".single-item").slick({
prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-left.png'>",
nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-right.png'>"
 });
```

Comment: when I use that code, the buttons are still above and below the carousel, they just change back to "next" and "previous" buttons, instead of arrows.  The way it looks in that fiddle is exactly what I'm looking for, I just can't seem to spot the difference.

Comment: Annand thanks for checking in! I was still having issues after trying all the advice, so I switched, I'm now using Owl Carousel and having an easier time getting it to do what I want.  https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/